# Prove that if $0<a<b$, then $a<\sqrt{ab}<\dfrac{a+b}{2}<b$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Prove that if $0<a<b$, then

$a<\sqrt{ab}<\dfrac{a+b}{2}<b.$

I have seen that the inequality $\sqrt{ab}\leq (a+b)/2$ is verified for all $a,b\geq 0$.

Comment: If you know the middle inequality, then the other two inequalities come from the assumption $0<a<b$: to see this, note $a=\sqrt{a\cdot a} < \sqrt{ab}$ and $b = (b+b)/2 > (a+b)/2$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that
$$a\lt b\implies\sqrt a\lt\sqrt b\implies \color{Red}{a\lt\sqrt{ab}}$$ and $$a\lt b\implies a+b\lt 2b\implies \color{Red}{\dfrac{a+b}{2}\lt b}.$$

Also expanding $$(\sqrt a-\sqrt b)^2\gt 0$$ yeild us $$\color{Red}{\sqrt {ab}\lt\dfrac{a+b}{2}}.$$ **Now combine all of them.**

Answer (score 2):

[image]

Proof without words. Imagine that the red segment is length $a$, and the blue segment is length $b$. See if you can find the lengths of the other segments.

Comment: This is beautifull. You should use different colors for $\sqrt{a \cdot b}$, though.

Answer (score 1):

This are $3$ inequalities, and $1$ is already solved. $2$ to go, lets solve them by equivalence transformations:

The first one ($a < \sqrt{ab}$):

\begin{align}
a &< \sqrt{ab} \\
a^2 &< ab \\
a &< b
\end{align}

The last one ($\dfrac{a+b}{2} < b$):
\begin{align}
\dfrac{a+b}{2} &< b \\
a + b &< 2 \cdot b \\
a &< b
\end{align}

Comment: Something bothers me about the order you're proving things. You should never start with what you want to prove.

Comment: @Hubble he mentioned that he would solve them by equivalence relations, it is easy for OP to start with $a < b$ and work his way up to the wanted inequality... sometimes starting with what you want to prove is the best way to find out how to prove it

Comment: He said equivalence transformations, not relations... In this simple case I have to disagree that starting with what you want is the best route, but to each his own I guess.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

As all numbers are positive, you can square the consequent, and you must establish

$$a^2<ab<\left(\frac{a+b}2\right)^2<b^2$$

or, subtracting $ab$,

$$a(a-b)<0<\left(\frac{a-b}2\right)^2<b(b-a).$$